# Sort by reference count php

Tags: php, user-controls

[image]

How can I sort by reference count?

In the above picture,
2-1
1-1
I want to go out like this.

I'm sorry for my bad english

Comment: you should provide some more info.  you marked it as a php question, but you only provided what appears to be a screenshot of phpmyadmin. ie - what have you tried so far?

Comment: There is also a picture link in blue text

Comment: This question is "unclear" because you didn't post your query which is actually generating `ref_source` using COUNT() & GROUP BY.  We can't guess such things.  In the future, do not submit your question until you have expressed every relevant detail.  Lack of information is sure to be one of the reason that your question was downvoted.  Asking "how to order by a single column" is not only a duplicate question on SO, it is even easier to directly research via online manuals.

Answer (score 0):

To sort a result set by a column you would append an `ORDER` clause to your query.

**For example:**

```
mysql> SELECT name, birth FROM pet ORDER BY birth;
+----------+------------+
| name     | birth      |
+----------+------------+
| Buffy    | 1989-05-13 |
| Bowser   | 1989-08-31 |
| Fang     | 1990-08-27 |
| Fluffy   | 1993-02-04 |
| Claws    | 1994-03-17 |
| Slim     | 1996-04-29 |
| Whistler | 1997-12-09 |
| Chirpy   | 1998-09-11 |
| Puffball | 1999-03-30 |
+----------+------------+
```

More information can be found in the manual:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: Sarcastic link only answer.. also more of a comment.

Comment: Sarcastic link ?It about sorting in `mysql` .Because the question is easy to answered only with the documentation I don't think that is sarcastic.

Comment: problem solved SELECT ref_source, count(ref_source) as total FROM table group by ref_source order by ref_source ASC